# Cassandra connector -- difference between joinWithCassandraTable and leftJoinWithCassandraTable -- Cannot Resolve symbol

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to access data from Cassandra by joining using the datastax cassandra connector. The below code is working for me. I am trying to sum up value columns from RDD and Cassandra after join

```
tm(a.joinWithCassandraTable("ks","tbl").on(SomeColumns("key","key2","key3","key4","key5","key6","key7","key8","key9","key10","key11","key12","key13","key14","key15","column1","column2","column3","column4","column5")).select("value1").map { case (ip, row) => IP(ip.key, ip.key2, ip.key3,ip.key4,ip.key5,ip.key6,ip.key7,ip.key8,ip.key9,ip.key10,ip.key11,ip.key12,ip.key13,ip.key14,ip.key15,ip.column1,ip.column2,ip.column3,ip.column4,ip.column5,ip.value1 + row.getLong("value1")) }.saveToCassandra("ks", "tbl"))
```

However, when I try to do a left join, it gives a "Cannot Resolve symbol **getLong**"
I believe this is due to the fact that left join does not guarantee a value, since it could be null, but I am not able to code this in scala.

```
tm(a.leftJoinWithCassandraTable("ks","tbl").on(SomeColumns("key","key2","key3","key4","key5","key6","key7","key8","key9","key10","key11","key12","key13","key14","key15","column1","column2","column3","column4","column5")).select("value1").map { case (ip, row) => IP(ip.key, ip.key2, ip.key3,ip.key4,ip.key5,ip.key6,ip.key7,ip.key8,ip.key9,ip.key10,ip.key11,ip.key12,ip.key13,ip.key14,ip.key15,ip.column1,ip.column2,ip.column3,ip.column4,ip.column5,ip.value1 + row.getLong("value1")) }.saveToCassandra("ks", "tbl"))
```

Any help is appreciated. If there is any information that is needed, let me know and I will try to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you don't get data in Cassandra, you should get an `Option[Row]` instead of `Row` object.

Instead of `.map { case (ip, row) =>  ...}` you can write:

```scala
.map { case (ip, row) => 
  row match {
    case None => ip
    case Some(data) => IP(...., ip.value1 + data.getLong("value1"))
  }
}
```

in this case - when you don't have data (`None`), then you just return `IP` object itself, and if you have data then you construct new `IP` object

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I had to change the return type of the overall method to return Unit (I had not specified anything earlier), since it was throwing an error saying the block is recursive. Not sure why it was recursive